# Qt video streaming application: no service found for qt.mediaplayer

Tags: c++, linux, qt, debian, video-streaming

I m trying to make a very simple QT QML appplication to stream a video from an ethernet camera (an Axis m3045v):
under windows 10 everything works fine, but as soon as I port the code under Debian 10, the application is not able to show the video stream and is returning this error...

`Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"`

I already installed **gstreaming** (GStreamer Core Library version 1.16.1) and **libqt5multimedia5-plugins** as suggested in other similar questions, without getting any results

Probably there is something very basic that I'm still missing, but as Linux beginner, I'm blocked here

Here the QML code :

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtMultimedia 5.12

ApplicationWindow {
visible: true
title: qsTr("test")
width: 1920
height: 1080
Video {
    id: videostream
    source: "rtsp://user::password@my_ip_address/axis-media/media.amp"
    autoPlay: true
    autoLoad: true
    anchors.top: parent.top
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
 } 
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

EDIT: I use QT Creator in both systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok
after several tries I found, I guess, the issue:
QT was built statically in my case so it needs to import explicitly the plugins used.
After checking qt multimedia installation prerequisites

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-requirements.html#multimedia-dependencies

And all the gstreaming libraries needed

I added explicitly on my .pro file the multimedia plugins (I was thinking QTCreator already adds all the needed references but obviously I was wrong...)

```
QT += multimedia multimediawidgets
```

And now it seems working fine, finally